# blazor "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor

how to fix the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". during the execution of the code `var lookup = await LookupClient.GetAllAsync(31);`. of all the code like this:

```
namespace Atana.Bc.Frontend.Client.Pages.BeaCukai
{
    public class LookupService
    {
        private IEnumerable<LookupDto> _lookupJenisDokumen;
        [Inject]
        public ILookupClient LookupClient { get; set; } = default;

        public IEnumerable<LookupDto> LookupJenisDokumenList
        {
            get { return _lookupJenisDokumen; }
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_lookupJenisDokumen, value))
                {
                    _lookupJenisDokumen = value;
                    Reload();
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task LoadLookup()
        {
            try
            {
                //'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
                var lookup = await LookupClient.GetAllAsync(31);
                    if (lookup != null)
                    {
                        LookupJenisDokumenList = lookup.Lookup;
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i am using blazor asp net 6 blazor. i want to create a global variable and which i will call "LookupJenisDokumenList".

Comment: post to program.cs ?

Comment: program.cs i have added "builder.Services.AddScoped<ILookupClient, LookupClient>();".
still "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Is this a fault from the backend?